# Sample latitude and longitude coordinates for database

Tags: mysql

does anyone know of a bunch of latitude and longitude coordinates that I can put in a mysql database?  I want to test if my PHP web service works on more than my three test coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get csv files containing latitude and longitude values from [US Board of Geographic Names](http://geonames.usgs.gov/domestic/download_data.htm)

You could take the csv file isolate the long and latitude info and import it into your SQL database.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, I think I can make this work, thanks for your response.

Comment: i think it's now geonames.nga.mil

Answer (score 1):

This could help you for countries

https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my app relies on showing users things near them, so I can't use a country.

Comment: If you want to get the location of exact location here you can get it from: http://www.mapcoordinates.net/en

Comment: But I need hundreds of those to test my app, although that's a useful link, thanks!

Comment: If you are interested you can use google API and fetch various locations: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro with PHP or something